# Change window title to the one in text box in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm just getting started with Objective-C and I'm writing a simple application.

I made two outlets :

- **wnd** - main window
- **display** - the text box

Then I've tried using this code:

```
[wnd setTitle:[display value]];
```

Unfortuanately it didn't work ...

The debugger said :

> 2010-05-22 XX:XX:08.577
>   HelloWorld[2536:a0f] -[NSTextField
>   value]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x102e032a0

Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not my forte, but try `stringValue` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

NSTextFiled does not have a method value - try stringValue. 
See [NSControl](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl) the superclass of NSTextField